# cant randomly set a new button with java

Tags: java, android, button, random, imagebutton

i am trying to get my buttons to change to a diffrent pic and a dif set of laws
it is an alphabet app that i currently have working and its on the market.... i want to make it randomly change the pic and then follow the alphebet through the whole program but i cant figure out how to get the buttons to randomize so here is the basic code that i am using

package com.alphafree;

```
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class letterA extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int[] _26Num = new int[6];
        int i, number;

        Random r1 = new Random(); // Random generator
        for (i = 1; i < _26Num.length; i++) { // Pick 6 Random Numbers
            do {
                number = (int) (r1.nextDouble() * 26);
                _26Num[1] = 1;
            } while (!(number != 0 && number != _26Num[1]
                    && number != _26Num[2] && number != _26Num[3]
                    && number != _26Num[4] && number != _26Num[5]));
            _26Num[i] = number;
        }

        // defines the buttons
        View but1 = findViewById(R.id.let1);
        View but2 = findViewById(R.id.let2);
        View but3 = findViewById(R.id.let3);
        View but4 = findViewById(R.id.let4);
        View but5 = findViewById(R.id.let5);

        but1.setOnClickListener(this);
        but2.setOnClickListener(this);
        but3.setOnClickListener(this);
        but4.setOnClickListener(this);
        but5.setOnClickListener(this);

        // set the random content view
        int random = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
        if (random == 1) {
            setContentView(R.layout.letter1a);

        } else if (random == 2) {
            setContentView(R.layout.letter1a);

        } else if (random == 3) {
            setContentView(R.layout.letter1a);

        } else if (random == 4) {
            setContentView(R.layout.letter1a);

        } else if (random == 5) {
            setContentView(R.layout.letter1a);

        }

        // here is were i need to set up the buttons
        if (_26Num[1] == 1) {

            let1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.let_a);

        } else if (_26Num[1] == 2) {
            setContentView(R.layout.letter1a);

        } 


    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (mp != null)
            mp.release();

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.let1:

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.correct);
            {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Y A Y!!!!   Y O U R    R I G H T")
                        .setMessage(
                                "Thats the letter      'A'                  You Chose Correct")
                        .setNeutralButton("Done", null).show();
                startActivity(new Intent("com.alphafree.LETTERB"));

            }
            break;

        }
        mp.seekTo(0);
        mp.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it about that way:

```
private static final int[] num2DrawableMap = new int[] {
    R.drawable.letterA,
    R.drawable.letterB,
    // etc
};

private static final int[] num2LayoutMap = new int[] {
    R.layout.layoutA,
    R.layout.layoutB,
    // etc
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    int[] _26Num = new int[6];
    int i, number;

    Random r1 = new Random(); // Random generator
    for (i = 1; i < _26Num.length; i++) { // Pick 6 Random Numbers
        do {
            // don't you like r1.nextInt(26) ?
            number = (int) (r1.nextDouble() * 26);
            // always 1? why in that loop?
            _26Num[1] = 1;
        } while (!(number != 0 && number != _26Num[1]
                && number != _26Num[2] && number != _26Num[3]
                && number != _26Num[4] && number != _26Num[5]));
        _26Num[i] = number;
    }

    // set the random content view
    int random = r1.nextInt(num2LayoutMap.size);
    setContentView(num2LayoutMap[random]);

    // find the buttons
    View[] buts = new View[5];
    buts[0] = findViewById(R.id.let1);
    buts[1] = findViewById(R.id.let2);
    buts[2] = findViewById(R.id.let3);
    buts[3] = findViewById(R.id.let4);
    buts[4] = findViewById(R.id.let5);

    for (View but : buts) {
        but.setOnClickListener(this);
        int drawableId = num2DrawableMap[_26Num[i]];
        but.setBackgroundResource(drawableId);
    }
}
```

But: the Buttons have to be inside every of your layout.xml files and they need to have the same id. Otherwise you don't find them. Also you need to `setContentView()` before you can use `findViewById()`

Comment: omg thank you ....so then i can set a view and then redefine it later as long as it is done before everthing finishes right?

Comment: you should use `setContentView()` only once between `onCreate` and `onDestroy` if you want to switch layouts dynamically you could set an empty `FrameLayout` as content and add / remove your layouts dynamically to that (or even just show / hide them). Or use different Activities.

Comment: oh wow ....i didnt realize that you coud do it that way ....thank you :)......y'all are SUCH a huge help :)

Answer (score 0):

Other than setContentView every time, Can you add all at a time and keep their visibility to GONE. what ever the button you want to display just make its visibility to VISIBLE. If you want to change make the Previous to GONE and make the new one VISIBLE.

Comment: nope :(.....the only thing i have ever been able to do to get the buttons to chang is start a new activity :( and it is just making the program WAY more masive than it needs to be